# Apostrophe problem in multiple-select fields

Tags: drupal, forms, select, checkbox, field

I have been fruitlessly searching for a solution for the following problem in Drupal.

Making a selection in a multiple-select field (i.e. a list of checkboxes) will yield an "Illegal Choice Detected" error if any of the choices contain apostrophes. This problem is referenced [here](http://drupal.org/node/354240). This field exists within registration and is not generated through either webforms or CCK.

Does anyone have any exact solution in mind, i.e. specific code to add to modules, or making particular updates?

Comment: So, how is the field generated? You say it is not through Webform or CCK, but the issue you link to is a Webform issue (which has been resolved). Is the field created by a custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of two php functions to generate strings:

1. [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
2. [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)